# refresh on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a javascript set timeout to close a div after 10 sec and I want to add a page refresh when the div is closed. The code I'm using is below.

```
<script>
var container_close_sec     = "100";
var closeTime               = container_close_sec * 100;

setTimeout("parent.close_div()", closeTime);

</script>
```

thanks

Comment: What does `parent.close_div()` do?  Does it do any animations?

Comment: no animation it just closes a div with an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var container_close_sec = 100;
var closeTime = container_close_sec * 100;

setTimeout(function() {
    parent.close_div(); // Closes div
    location.href = location.href; // Refresh page
}, closeTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is:

```
var container_close_sec     = "100";
var closeTime               = container_close_sec * 100;

setTimeout(location.reload, closeTime);
```

But I don't understand why you care to close the div if you are just going to refresh the page.

If you want to close the div and refresh see @DontVoteMeDown's answer.  My simply will reload the page after close time.